# Jacobi formula for matrices: variation

Tags: matrices, determinant

Jacobi’s formula says: $\frac{d}{dt}\text{det}(A(t))=\text{det}(A(t)) \cdot \text{tr}(\text{Ad}(A(t))\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(A(t))$.

Exists a variation of the Jacobi’s formula where $\text{det}(\frac{d}{dt}(A(t))$ is involved?

Comment: You can apply that formula to $B(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(A(t))$ if $A(t)$ is twice differentiable, but I'm not sure whether that's what you're after.

Comment: Thank you, but no. I was thinking about a relation involving $\text{det}(A(t))$, $\frac{d}{dt}\text{det}(A(t))$ and $\frac{d}{dt}(A(t))$.